# Closing tabs when a chrome extension is disabled/reloaded

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that opens a number of tabs, which it keeps open and uses to display data.  I want those tabs to close when the extension is disabled or reloaded.  My initial thought was that background.html would be unloaded when I restarted the plugin, but I can't seem to get anything that involves this to work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome automatically closes pages with `chrome-extension://<your_extension_id>/local.html` urls (pages from the extension directory) when an extension is disabled. So if you can display your data using those pages - they will get closed. If it is some external site you are displaying - maybe you can make a local stub page with iframe and load your external site there.

Otherwise I can't think about any other way (besides having another extension watching this one).

Comment: Oh, excellent.  I love it when the answer to my question turns out to be "do nothing". I hadn't actually set the tabs to display anything yet, but if I had, Chrome would have closed them all by itself.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i dont' know so much about chrome extensions, but, I think you are openning new windows by something like var w = window.open(params), so, you can close the window with w.close().

if not, ignore my answer :P